# Sublime Text Html Word Counter

Tags: html, regex, sublimetext3

I have an HTML document, `mystory.html`. This document holds the following:

```
<body>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>This document holds seven words.</p>
</body>
```

I want to be able to use `cmd + f` and find all of the words that are NOT HTML tags via regex. I would download a plugin via package installer that counts words in the HTML, but it does not exist 8(

I have used the following regex to try to do something similar, but the problem with it is that it counts the `bod` in body and if any tag name length is greater than 1 the regex also selects it. The code is `(?:)[a-zA-Z']+(?!>)`. None of these tags have any properties or css. Basically, I want to count the number of words in the document that ARE NOT HTML TAGS. If anyone knows a plugin, I will also accept that answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the regex:

```
\b[\w']+\b(?!>)
```

- word boundary
- followed by a word
- followed by a word boundary
- not followed by `>`

This returns 7 matches.

[image: html words]